# table column text is greater than column width?

Tags: html

I have some text in table column which is greater than the column width I want. So text is overflowing from it. So I apply `overflow:auto` but in this case it is showing scroll on every page where data is less than the width of the column.

I don't want to show the scroll on that page where data is less than the width of column just want to show only where data is greater than its length.

Does any one have some suggestions?

```
<td  style=" width:50%;overflow:auto;>
```

Comment: Try to wrap td content in div with fixed width and overflow: auto.

Comment: I've added answer, vote this please.

Comment: hey firefox is not implementing word-wrap how to deal with it???

Comment: word-wrap should work in firefox, if you have very long words without spaces you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` ([link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820384/how-can-i-mimic-text-overflow-ellipsis-in-firefox) - for previous versions of firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap td content in div with fixed `width` and `overflow: auto`

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>  <!-- your fixed width column -->
       <div style="width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
          Loremipsumdolorsitametconsectetuadipisicingelit
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use this <td  style=" width:50%;overflow:scroll;"> 
This will insert horizontal and vertical scrollbars.
They will become active only if the content requires it.
```